# How can I contain an iframe video so that it doesn't load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am adding video `<iframes>` to a page but I want them to be contained in something so they dont show/load until I want to show the video (and therefore load all the video stuff).

Imagine 100 videos on a page, I dont want to load everything upfront. But only when needed. But I DO want the source (i.e. embed code) to appear on the page to make it easy for admins

Comment: If it's about youtube videos in iframes he's something I wrote a while ago that might be able to help https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/4eLq6td6/

Comment: @AndrewBone `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/link2twenty/4eLq6td6/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/G2KlPOYu6U8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` Try adding `https:` protocol at `iframe.src`

Comment: @guest271314 sorted thanks.

Comment: @AndrewBone This is same process described at Answer below, yes?

Comment: @guest271314 same process only very youtube specific.

Answer (score 1):

> but I want them to be contained in something so they dont
>   show/trigger untill I want to show the video (and therefore load all
>   teh video stuff)

Do not include `src` attribute at `<video></video>` elements until you want to play the video. When you add the `src` attribute to `<video>` element, you can call `.load()`, `.play()` on the `video` element to play the video.

Comment: When did he ask for `<video>`? I only read `iframes`, suggesting maybe youtube-videos?

Comment: @Arg0n _"I am adding video <iframes> to a page"_ , _"Imagine 100 videos on a page"_

Comment: Exactly, so where is the `<video>` html-tag in the question?

Comment: @Arg0n _"Exactly, so where is the `<video>` html-tag in the question?"_ How else are videos played in `html`? OP can use `<video>` elements to achieve expected result

Comment: E.g. with `<iframe>`. `<iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxx"></iframe>`

Comment: @Arg0n Why would OP do this if they want to control when video is loaded and played?

Comment: this is a iframe question and it could be anything within the iframe, just so happens in my example it will be a video embed which could be video or flash depending on your system

Comment: @benbyford The same process applies. Do not include `src` at `<iframe>` element `html` until you want to load the resource. _"this is a iframe question and it could be anything within the iframe"_ The actual Question at original post describes loading videos, not "could be anything within the iframe"

Comment: ok, but I still need the src on the page to call it, but then it would load. soooooo how would you get around this. currently I've wrapped the iframe in a <script> tag but this is not ideal.

Comment: @benbyford _"ok, but I still need the src on the page to call it, but then it would load. soooooo how would you get around this."_ ? Requirement at Question states _" I dont want to load everything upfront."_ . Do not include `src` attribute at initial `html`. Add the `src` attribute pointing to the resource at  the `iframe` element when you want to load the resource.

Comment: this is from a free text field from any user so it could be an embed from any video provider, im guessing it isn't possible then to supress loading an iframe with a src attr set

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not incredibly clear, I think you are asking is there a way I can load iframes on the fly so my page doesn't load really slowly.

The answer to that is yes, there are many ways to do that, I don't know which implementation is best for you but here is a little mock up of a possible solution.

```js
showFrame = function(url, id) {
  var iframe = document.querySelector(id);
  iframe.style.display = "block";
  iframe.src = url;
};

hideFrame = function(id) {
  var iframe = document.querySelector(id);
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  iframe.src = "";
};

toggleFrame = function(url, id) {
  var iframe = document.querySelector(id);
  if (iframe.style.display == 'none') {
    showFrame(url, id);
  } else if (iframe.src == url) {
    hideFrame(id);
  } else {
    showFrame(url, id);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.menu {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.menu button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
}
#iframe_cont {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <button onclick="toggleFrame('https://www.google.com/maps/embed','#iframe_cont')">Example 1</button>
  <button onclick="toggleFrame('https://youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c','#iframe_cont')">Example 2</button>
  <button onclick="toggleFrame('https://youtube.com/embed/-YGDyPAwQz0','#iframe_cont')">Example 3</button>
</div>

<iframe id="iframe_cont" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks! this would definatly work but Ideally I would like a user to add the embed code from youtube or whatever so the src would be in the iframe not on any buttons or array somewhere. I mainly just want to stop the iframe from is default behaviour and start it at will.